Tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$ and p-adic integer ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$
Thanks for your reading. Suppose we have two $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules $A,B$. Do we always have $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B \simeq A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} B$, as abelian groups or $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules? Here $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module could be given by multiplication on left or right item of the tensor. If not, in which cases is it true?
The motivation is when I read many arithmetic geometry papers, I see many authors will just write tensor without subscript, which I think means tensor over $\mathbb{Z}$, though according to background of text it should be tensor over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
I get some hints from @Geoffrey Trang. For a commutative ring $R$ and two $R$-modules $A$ and $B$, where every $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map between $R$-modules is automatically $R$
-linear, we can have the two tensor isomorphic as abelian groups. It is true for $R=Z/nZ$, but also for $R=\mathbb{Q}$, and more generally, whenever $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ is an epimorphism in the category of commutative rings. So, I think since $\mathbb{Z}→\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an epimorphism in the category (and by completion under $p$-adic topology and definition of epimorphism), we have the two tensor over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are isomorphic as abelian groups.
Besides, the two $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module structure on $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$ are the same also due to $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ is epimorphism. And it will be true for any $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ epimorphism. This point is obtained also by @Geoffrey Trang's hint.
Are the results listed above right? If right, why the equivalence of the two kinds of linear maps, $\mathbb{Z},R$ gives the equivalence of the two tensor?( I guess by some hom-tensor adjunction?)
And, why epimorphism condition gives us the equivalence of the two kinds of linear maps, and the equivalence of the two kinds of module? Moreover, is the converse of the question true? Like if the two kinds of linear maps are equivalent, do we have $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ epimorphism?

Inclusion of integers into p-adics is NOT an epimorphism. Cardinality of the target of a ring epimorphism never excess the cardinality of its domain. A ring morphism $R \to S$ is epi iff the multiplication map of $R$-bimodules $S \otimes_R S \to S$ is an isomorphism; or, equivalently, when restriction of scalars is a fully faithful embedding.

Also it's easy to show that the essential image of restriction of scalars along an epimorphism $R \to S$ is closed under taking subobjects in the ambient category of R-modules. (Actually, those images are characterised as subcategories which are closed under subobjects, quotients, sums and products. This is Gabriel-de la Peña theorem.) $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb Z_p$ clearly does not admit a structure of a $\Bbb Z_p$-module.

"I see many authors will just write tensor without subscript, which I think means tensor over $\mathbb Z$."  There is no such convention. When a ring is not indicated in the tensor product, you're just expected to know by context which ring is meant. It seems the whole motivation behind your post is due to this misunderstanding.

@Denis T Thanks very much for pointing my mistake. I will amend it later.

@KConrad Thanks for your comment. If there is no special interpretation on context, where I can just find R-modules M and N, should I assume the tensor without subscript means tensor for R-modules?

@Rellw  well sure, when there is only one ring $R$ it's reasonable to assume that.  But I can't promise you will never see a counterexample. Just pay attention to what is happening.

No, $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}_p$ is much larger than $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p}\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}_p$. To see this, observe that $\mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z}$ is $p$-torsion free and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is $p$-local, so $\mathrm{Tor}_1(\mathbb{Z}_p, \mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z})=0$, and we have an exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z})\to 0.
$$
Next, the term on the right is in fact a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space: multiplication with $p$ is invertible on $\mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z}$, and multiplication with numbers coprime to $p$ is invertible on $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so every integer acts invertibly on $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z})$. Tensoring a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space with $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't change its value, so
$$
\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z})  \cong (\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z}) )\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} (\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Q}). 
$$
As $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is an uncountable $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, so is this tensor product. So the above exact sequence, which is split by the multiplication map $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_p$, proves that
$$
\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \text{uncountable $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space}
$$
Nonetheless, the category of $p$-complete abelian groups carries a symmetric-monoidal structure given by the $p$-completed tensor product, i.e. tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$ followed by $p$-completion, and sometimes this might also just be denoted by the symbol $\otimes$.

To add to Achim's answer, Bousfield and Kan, "The core of a ring" JPAA 1972 and (correction) 1973 define a ring $R$ to be a "solid" if the multiplication map $R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}R\to R$ is an isomorphism. They then go on to characterise solid rings. There is also a related discussion on page 44 of their book, "Homotopy limits, completions and localizations".
If a ring $R$ is solid, then for any right $R$-module $A$ and left $R$-module $B$, we have $$A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B \cong A\otimes_R R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R \otimes_R B \cong A\otimes_R R \otimes_R B\cong A\otimes_R B.$$
So your question is asking whether the ring of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is solid.
The ring of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is not solid in the sense of Bousfield and Kan. This follows from their paper, or from the answer of Achim above.
